# clang-formatter: Prevent new line in function declaration

Tags: ios, objective-c, code-formatting, clang-format

In `Objective-C` how to prevent new lines here:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
    numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
```

to see this:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
```

Tried this, but apparently not works with `Objective-C`:

```
AllowAllParametersOfDeclarationOnNextLine: false
```